# Ruby Curl::Multi.http 302 redirect problems

Tags: ruby

I seem to be having a problem with 302 redirects using curb (Ruby's curl programs)

Here's the code snippet that is ** NOT working** (it's NOT doing the 302 redirect)

> ```
> easy_options = {:follow_location => true, :enable_cookies => true, :useragent => 'curb', :cookiefile => 'cookie.txt'}
> multi_options = {:pipeline => true}
> url_fields = [
>     {
>         :url => 'https://x.y.z/webapps/login/',
>         :method => :post,
>         :follow_location => true,
>         :enable_cookies => true,
>         :useragent => 'curb',
>         :post_fields => {
>             'user_id' => 'xxxx',
>             'password' => 'xxxx',
>             'action' => 'login',
>             'encoded_pw' => Base64.strict_encode64('xxxx')},
>     }
>
> ]
>
> Curl::Multi.http(url_fields,{:pipeline => true}) do |easy, code, method|
>  puts easy.header_str
> end
> ```

Here's the code snippet that **appears to be working** (it's doing the 302 redirect)

> ```
> easy_options = {:follow_location => true, :enable_cookies => true, :useragent => 'curb', :cookiefile => 'cookie.txt'}
> multi_options = {:pipeline => true}
>
> url_fields = [
>     { :url => 'https://x.y.z/webapps/login/',
>       :post_fields => {
>           'user_id' => 'xxxx',
>           'password' => 'yyyy',
>           'action' => 'login',
>           'encoded_pw' => Base64.strict_encode64('yyyy')}}
> ]
>
> Curl::Multi.post(url_fields, easy_options, multi_options) do|easy|
>   # do something interesting with the easy response
>   puts easy.last_effective_url
> end
> ```

Question:  Why is the first block not doing the 302 redirect as expected?  :follow_location is set to true?
Thanks in advance!

Let me know if you need more information